# Visual Studio doesn't show up. At all. What the heck?

Tags: visual-studio

For the past six hours, I have been tying to set up Microsoft Visual Studio Express. Theoretically, it got installed. I still can't compile using it. I can't even find it. But, fortunately for me, being a student, I got Visual Studio Professional for free! Woo hoo! Now let's install it. And it is installed!

Now where the hell is it? I have searched Program Files, Program Files (x86), and my actual Program Menu. It. Isn't. There. However, when I go to the Control Panel to see if it can be uninstalled, it IS there. Yay! Okay, let's "Change" it. Oh look, a repair button, let's click that. This should fix everythi- My computer just utterly froze. Completely and fully. No ctrl-alt-delete. No mouse cursor. Nothing.

Now, I cannot be the only person who has this problem. I am running a very common operating system on very common components. And yet no where online can I find even a single solution.

So, in short: I installed both Visual Studio Express (which did not show up in programs or even with command prompt commands), Visual Studio Professional (which didn't show up in programs or even with command prompt commands) and attempting to uninstall either of them completely locks down my computer, freezing the screen(s) for good. This has happened twice Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

I am going to try to restart and repair one more time. If that doesn't work, I guess I'm stuck.

EDIT: SPECS:
Operating System: Windows 7 64-bit

Software: Visual Studio Professional 2013 32-bit (no 64-bit available through Dreamspark) no editing of options during install

EDIT: On the fourth restart and repair, I got a BSOD. =/

Comment: Operating system and version? Visual Studio version?  64bit / 32 bit?  During the installation, did you change any of the defaults?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I thought I had listed my specs already. My computer froze a second time in the process of writing this. Let me edit the main post with my specs.

Comment: Does HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio exist in the registry?

Comment: "On the fourth restart and repair, I got a BSOD": I bet you have an antivirus or firewall that's causing some problems.  Try rebooting (again), disabling those and reinstalling VS.

Comment: WWith regard to the registry entry: I did not think to look at that, but now that I have check it is indeed missing. As far as the antivirus and firewall, I was able to download and run the install, and neither my firewall nor my antivirus is configured to stop anything from Microsoft.

Comment: I am confused as to how this is considered "off-topic". In the quoted reason, it specifically states "unless [general computing hardware and software] directly involve tools used primarily for programming." Visual studio is literally only used for programming, no "primarily" about it. On top of that, one of the answers (the one I accepted) has two upvotes, meaning that it obviously helped someone fix a problem. This cannot possibly be considered off-topic by any metric presented to users on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to install VS and are thinking looking for ways to avoid problems, please read this!

Another thing you can do is to not install Visual Studio until you have followed your steps 1 through 2. If you are just starting, please don't try to install this while running anything else. It will likely mess something up, at which point you will have to go through the complex process which b4ux1t3 outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got it installed.

If you are having problems similar to the ones I was having in the question, follow these steps:

1. Completely uninstall all versions of Visual Studio (this includes Professional and Express versions)
2. Close all other windows and programs. I even went as far as to turn off Dropbox and Google Drive syncing.
3. Install Visual Studio again.
4. Actually restart your computer. This matters.

The following steps are only necessary if Visual Studio gives the error "The operation could not be completed. No such interface exists." when you try to start it up.

1. Restart your computer. If the error still occurs, go to Start > Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program
2. Find the Visual Studio program, right click it, and click "Change."
3. When the familiar installation window pops up, click repair.
4. When it finishes, actually restart your computer. Again, this matters.

It should now be working. It was for me.